# Update existing Eventbridge Rule to include a new target using CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I have two separate applications that need to update the target of an EventBridge rule. What is the best way to handle this? Should I create a separate EventBridge rule that has the same source or is there a way to update the actual EventBridge rule in both serverless applications without error?

I have tried to add the EventBridge rule in both applications but it throws an error saying that the resource already exists.

To visualize I have the following:

[image: diagram showing the current setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) your existing EB rule into CloudFormation stack before you can modify it. Alternatively, you can develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) which can modify the rule without importing.

Comment: Interesting. So I should be able to define this EventBridge rule as a custom resource in both target applications and just update the rule that way? I'll have to see if there's an example of that out there. Their documentation offers me little help unfortunately.